# Histogram on main diagonal of pairs function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a correlation matrix in R with histograms on main diagonal using:

```
pairs(credit[,-(4:5)], diag.panel=panel.hist)
```

But I get

```
object 'panel.hist' not found
```

What's wrong?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156800/ask-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7):

Have you executed code to define the panel.hist function?  As per the example in the pairs documentation (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pairs.html):

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
    h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
    breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
    y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
    rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col = "cyan", ...)
}
```

You need to run this code to define the panel.hist function in your environment before referencing it in `pairs()`

Comment: Thanks. Finally,  I figured it out a possible solution. If I use: `install.packages("BioStatR")
library(BioStatR)
pairs(credit[,-(4:5)], diag.panel =  panel.hist) ` Now it works.